# How can I estimate the total number of yeast cell in a medium?

Tags: experimental-design, yeast

So I want to run an experiment with yeast. I want to monitor the population as close as possible in regard to its size. I am aware I could use a colorimeter or such, but I can only get a microscope. Is there a way I can estimate the population with a microscope?

Answer (score 3):

Determination of cell concentration using a microscope is usually done by using a hemocytometer, also called counting chamber or Neubauer-counting chamber.

Basically, you count the cells in a defined volume within a specific area. This way you can calculate the concentration in your medium and also the total cell count.

I found a good explanation especially for counting yeast cells [here](https://eurekabrewing.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/yeast-basics-counting-yeast-cells/).

Comment: Is there a way to find the concentration without using a hemocytometer?

Comment: @BrianBlumberg You can plate the cells after serial dilution and count the colonies. Since you mentioned that you want to use a microscope, you need to use a haemocytometer; you cannot estimate true concentration on a normal slide. Also, haemocytometer is more accurate than OD, if the cells have different sizes.